# Dynamically sum cells on current row starting at a specific column, and ending on the column before current cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How would you add all the numbers in the current row(dynamic address) starting at specific column and leading up to the column one left of current cell? I want the row and column references dynamic to handle insertions and removals of columns and rows

Basic spreadsheet to demonstrate
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15MzHnGnW1uR0Pvb_npEJKZOELu_PYPz0L6eb3Zh9LRA/edit#gid=0

Is this correct, if I am adding starting on column 3

`=SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),3,4) &":"&ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()-1,4)`

Comment: I think that you should reword the question. What have you tried to verify that the formula works as you need? What is stopping you from verifying the formula by yourself? What led you to use this formula instead of using a regular range reference?

Comment: I came up with the formula after posting the question. This will be a template for different months with the number of columns changing, so the formula keeps the references correct regardless of copying pasting inserting and removing of columns

Comment: HI, @whatsnewsisyphus So, have you answered your own question? Or is there still a problem to resolve? If there _is_ a problem, may I respectfully remind you: `Do NOT share spreadsheets/images as the only source of data. Use markdown TEXT tables instead.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),3,4) &":"&ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()-1,4)
```

seems to solve my problem, though it seems a bit unwieldy.